# VB.NET ~ Need to know how to click on this href

Tags: vb.net, browser

I have this link (not a button) that I want to click on ...I don't want to navigate to the link via webbrowser1.navigate("") because the link changes but the href and inner text is always the same.

Here is the HTML of the link

Should this be put into the webbrowser or behind a button

```
<ul id="nav">
<li>
<li>
<li>
<a href="/submit/">Submit a New Story</a>
</li>
<li>
</ul>
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: You've probably deleted enough of your questions that you're autobanned by the system.  That, and you insist on prefacing your titles with tags and ask programming questions on [meta].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the result you're seeking for, but if you want to trigger a click as if the client would have clicked it, you could achieve it by obtaining the [`WebBrowser.Documentproperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document.aspx) which returns a [`HtmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.aspx) class, you can retrieve that `a` tag then trigger a click on it.

The [`All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.all.aspx) property should be a good start:

```
var aTag = d.All.Where(a => a.TagName == "a");
```